# natbib square/number citations: number the citations by order of their occurrence in the document

Tags: bibliographies, citing, natbib, elsarticle

I am writing a paper with IEEE referencing pattern. I'd like the references to be numbered **by order of their occurrence in the document**. For example:

#### `references.bib`

```
@article{Suhai,
    author = {Suhai, S.},
    journal = {Phys. Rev. B},
    volume = 27,
    year = 1983,
    pages = {3506-18},
    url = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevB.27.3506}
}
@article{Zuhai,
    author = {Zuhai, S.},
    journal = {Phys. Rev. B},
    volume = 27,
    year = 1993,
    pages = {3506-18},
    url = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevB.27.3506}
}
```

#### `main.tex`

```
\documentclass[review,numbers,square]{elsarticle}
\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat} %for bibliography
\begin{document}
    One\cite{Zuhai} and Two\cite{Suhai}
    \bibliography{references}
\end{document}
```

What I get is this:

[image: Output of my LaTeX]

But what I need is the following:

[image]

Unfortunately, I am stuck with `natbib` because it comes along with `elsarticle`. Therefore, using the package `biblatex` gives an error as it clashes with `natbib`. If there is a way I can unload `natbib` from `elsarticle`, so that I can use `biblatex`, that would also be great!

Note: Some other posts suggested to use `\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}` but that didn't help either.

Comment: In the MWE `\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}` works for me, i.e. results in "One[1] and Two[2]" in the citation and the bibliography is [1] Zuhai and [2] Suhai. You need to run LaTeX, BibTeX, LaTeX, LaTeX after you changed the style. If you want to submit to an Elsevier journal (that's about the only reason why one should be using the `elsarticle` document class), you may want to check the author instructions whether or not you should use one of the `.bst` bibliography styles provided by Elsevier (`\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num}`) instead of the plain `natbib` ones.

Comment: ... If on the other hand you need real IEEE style, there are styles like `IEEEtran.bst`: `\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}`. But I'm not sure what Elsevier would say about using IEEE styles instead of their own.

Comment: You are using `elsarticle`, which is specifically for submissions to the Elsevier journal 'stable', and which follows the rules they set. I can't imagine that they will let you use IEEE style: just stick with what they provide.

Comment: @moewe 'unsrtnat' works, why don't you post it as answer?

Comment: @EnthusiasticEngineer Mico's answer already mentions `unsrtnat`. Given that it may not be the best of ideas to recommend `unsrtnat` with Elsevier classes (see Joseph's and my comments above) I wouldn't want to add another answer that says the same and might on a quick skim be misconstrued to advocate using `unsrtnat` with Elsevier classes.

Comment: @moewe you are right, by the way your comment solved my problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue of whether bibliographic entries are either sorted alphabetically by authors' surnames or are listed by order of their first citation in the body of the document is *not* determined by the `natbib` citation management package. Instead, the sorting issue is determined by the choice of bibliography style: Some styles are set up to instruct BibTeX to perform alphabetical sorting, whereas others do not.

As you've "discovered", the `abbrvnat` bibliography style is programmed to perform alphabetical sorting. If you are otherwise satisfied by the way `abbrvnat` formats the bibliographic references, you may consider switching to the `unsrtnat` bibliography style. After switching bibliography styles, be sure to run LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more to fully propagate all changes.

However, as @moewe and @JosephWright have already pointed out in comments, you really must find out, from the editorial office of the Elsevier-stable journal to which you intend to submit a paper to, which bibliography styles are acceptable. You may well learn that neither `abbrvnat` nor `unsrtnat` are acceptable to the journal -- and that you should be employing a bib style such as the `elarticle-num`.